# Android 12 splash screen on Xiaomi Miui

Tags: android

I implemented new splash screen of Android 12 with **Theme.SplashScreen**.
But it not working on **Xiaomi MIUI** devices with force dark mode.
**android:forceDarkAllowed** does'n help on splash theme.

Can anyone know how to solve this problem?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score -2):

I found one solution - apply dark theme for splash screen

Comment: Can you explain this in detail?

Comment: no enogh answer

Comment: I just created night variant staring theme with <item name="windowSplashScreenBackground">@color/black</item>